# EnvironmentObject and SceneDelegate on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I wanna make some app on macOS using SwfitUI.

Following the iOS, there is `SceneDelegate` (after iOS 13). But in macOS, there is only `AppDelegate`.

OK. I wanna use `environmentObject` on `SceneDelegate`'s `scene` method

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView
            .environmentObject(mainController)
        )
```

to use `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper in my `ContentView`.

Literally I can't implement `.environmentObject()` cuz in macOS there is no `SceneDelegate`!

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is default generated AppDelegate for macOS SwiftUI project, and how environment object can be set for content view in it.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Create content view
    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(AppSettings())

    // Create the window and set the content view. 
    window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.center()
    window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    window.autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop = true
}
```